# IFunctionExceptionFilter and Writing a response

Tags: azure-functions

I am using Azure functions and trying to write a generic exception filter using IFunctionExceptionFilter and IHttpContextAccessor. It works and I can set header variables in the response. However, the response body is blank no matter what I try.

```
public abstract class BaseAPI : IFunctionExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    protected BaseAPI(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.responseValidator = responseValidator;
    }

    public async Task OnExceptionAsync(FunctionExceptionContext exceptionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
        httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("MyHeader", "Foo"); // this works and appears
        await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Some text"); // this is not shown in the response
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to get the body response appearing? I have tried using Response.Body directly but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this question in search of a proper OnExceptionAsync implementation. And the only thing is missing in code is a response content type and length.

```
    public async Task OnExceptionAsync(FunctionExceptionContext exceptionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
            var text = "Some text"; // text variable
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"; // Missing part
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("MyHeader", "Foo");
            await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(text);
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.ContentLength = text.Length; // Missing part
    }
```

Tested in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge. Hope it helps.

Update, from @ChrisHG, one string is missing

```
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.CompleteAsync()
```

Alternatively, the string I`m using now.

```
await response.WriteAsync(errorMessage, Encoding.UTF8, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: This nearly worked for me but I also had to do `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.CompleteAsync()` for the text to be returned.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @ChrisHG ! Indeed it was a not full answer and will update the response with CompleteAsync().

The last line that I`m using in my solution is:

await response.WriteAsync(errorMessage, Encoding.UTF8, cancellationToken);

Comment: I don't get it. Everything works, the content type is set, the status code is set, the header is set, but as soon as I do anything with the body, the request gets aborted and I get no reponse at all in Postman.